# Как подключится к запущенному консольному приложению

Tags: c#

Имеем уже запущенное консольное приложение.

Если ли возможность подключится к нему по StdIO?
Вроде как консольные приложения изначально многопоточные и вроде это можно сделать.

Запустить новый экземпляр этого консольного приложения не вариант - они подерутся за оборудование!

Подскажите куда копать? Ключевые слова!

ЗЫ: Windows, C#

Comment: А причём тут многопоточность? Непонятно. (Ну и нет, никакие приложения не являются изначально многопоточными.)

Comment: А что вы хотите сделать? Что для вас означает «подключиться»?

Comment: Вы хотите подключиться к стандартному вводу/выводу консольного приложения?

Comment: Да, именно!  Хочу подключиться к стандартному вводу/выводу уже запущенного консольного приложения!

Comment: @ДмитрийГарбуз Вам обязательно именно подключиться? Или у вас есть возможность сначала запустить свою программу-прослушку, а потом консольное?

Comment: Нет, консольное приложение запускает Chrome. 
Т.е. нужно именно подключится.